# Bit representation of the hashing multiplication method

Tags: hashing

In the picture below from [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLRS), I fail to understand **why** exactly $h(k)$ = the $p$ **highest-order** bits of the **lower** **w-bit** half of the product.

For context, this is supposed to compute 
$h(k) = \lfloor m (k A \;  \text{mod} 1) \rfloor $

[image]

---

For further context, CLRS mentions the following, but I still don't quite get why those $p$ **highest-order** bits are the ones we are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(kA \bmod 1)$ is in the range $[0,1)$. So multiplying that by $2^p$ gives a number in the range $[0,2^p)$. That is:

$$\left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right \rfloor  \bmod 2^p$$

Once you've worked that out, it's not too hard to see:

$$\left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right \rfloor  \bmod 2^p = \left\lfloor kA 2^p  \right\rfloor \bmod 2^p = \left\lfloor \frac{ks}{2^{w-p}}  \right\rfloor \bmod 2^p$$

So you can implement this by taking $ks$, shifting it $w-p$ bits to the right, then taking the lowest order $p$ bits. Which is exactly the same as taking the highest order $p$ bits of the low word.

Comment: In case it helps others who reads this: The result of $x \; \text{mod} \; b^p$ is the last $p$ digits of the number $x$ represented in base $b$. For example: $x \; \text{mod} \; 10$ gives you the last digit of $x$ in base 10. Similarly, $x \; \text{mod} \; 100$ gives you the last two digits of $x$ in base 10, etc.

Comment: Maybe I read this too quickly, sorry. I fail to see the first equivalence:
$$\left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right \rfloor  \bmod 2^p$$

Comment: Do you $(kA see that \bmod 1) \in [0,1)$? Therefore $\left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right\rfloor < 2^p$.

Comment: Thanks - the first formula that you wrote in your comment just above didn't come out well, but I think I follow you. I see that  $(k A \bmod 1) \in [0,1)$, i.e. this formula takes the _fractional_ part of the product $kA$ so the result must be $\in [0, 1)$. I also see that if $n$ is a positive integer and $x \in [0,1)$, we must have $n x \leq n$, and thus we would also have $n x \bmod n \leq n$. Is that the argument behind the first Eq. in your answer, i.e. $\left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right \rfloor  \bmod 2^p$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thanks! And the last bit, why is it that $\left\lfloor 2^p (kA \bmod 1) \right \rfloor  \bmod 2^p = \left\lfloor kA 2^p  \right\rfloor \bmod 2^p$ ? (i.e. why can we "drop" the $\text{mod} \;1$ part?

Comment: Because the $\bmod 2^p$ part does the job.

Comment: @Pseudonym Can you please elaborate on the last part a bit further?